# AWS API Gateway. Origin has been blocked by CORS Policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cors, aws-api-gateway

Framework: Vue.js

Sending DELETE request(axios) to aws api gateway, that triggers a lambda function.

In API Gateway, I have created the DELETE method
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UWW4.jpg)

I have created/configured the OPTIONS method, where Gateway Responses DEFAULT 4XX AND DEFAULT 5XX are checked. Methods: DELETE and OPTIONS are checked, Access-Control-Allow-Headers: 'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token' and Access-Control-Allow-Origin were manually set. i.e. a list of origins.

I confirm configuration was saved by taking a look at Gateway Responses
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3g70.jpg)

Lambda Function created, responds with the following headers.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Zo35.png)

Code on client side
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBvrD.png)

Executing program - Request Response does not include the Access-Control-Allow-Origins.

I've been stuck for a couple of days now, I don't know where else I should look into.

I have tried adding headers to request e.g. Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '*' ,and tried the list of specific origins that will ping the api.
set Access-Control-Allow-Origin in api gateway to '*'
uncheck Lambda Proxy Integration in Delete Method, Any Method in api gateway
lambda function response with 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'list of methods'
use fetch

Comment: Do you see the OPTIONS request in your Network tab in the browser when you send the request? If so, what is the response of it?

Comment: @Brian No, absolutely no sign of OPTIONS in my Network tab.

Comment: If you're making a DELETE request to a different origin, then your browser should send an OPTIONS request. Are you sure you're making the call to the correct origin? See:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @Brian yes, I'm making the call to the correct origin. I even had someone take a look with me to double-check that. Just in case I'm dyslexic and didn't even notice.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.